# How to unit test and check if a function is calling the expected firebase method in Jest?

Tags: javascript, typescript, unit-testing, firebase-authentication, jestjs

In `App.ts` I am calling `firebase.auth().signInWithEmailAndPassword(email, password)` method

Now I want to unit test to check that when the `myAuthenticationPlugin.authenticate(email, password)` method is called from `App.spec.ts` it also calls  `firebase.auth().signInWithEmailAndPassword(email, password)` method since that is what the `App.ts` essentially does ..

I have tried multiple work-arounds with no avail.

**App.ts**

```
const App= {
    authenticate: async (email, password) => {
        await firebase.auth().signInWithEmailAndPassword(email, password)
  },
}
```

**App.spec.ts**

```
import myAuthenticationPlugin from 'authenticationPlugin/App'
import firebase from 'firebase/app'
jest.mock('firebase/app', () => {
  const firebase = {
    auth: jest.fn(() => {
      return {
        currentUser: {
          email: 'test',
          uid: '123',
          emailVerified: true
        },

        signInWithEmailAndPassword: jest.fn().mockImplementation()
      }
    }),
    initializeApp: jest.fn()
  }
  return firebase
})

describe('Test for authenticate ()', () => {
    it('signInWithEmailAndPassword ()', () => {
      const email = 'test'
      const password = 'mypassword'
      myAuthenticationPlugin.authenticate(email, password)
      expect(firebase.auth().signInWithEmailAndPassword).toHaveBeenCalled()
    })
  })
```

**Error i recieve**

```
● App.js (Authentication Plugin) › Test for authenticate () › signInWithEmailAndPassword ()

    expect(jest.fn()).toHaveBeenCalled()

    Expected number of calls: >= 1
    Received number of calls:    0

      44 |       const password = 'mypassword'
      45 |       myAuthenticationPlugin.authenticate(email, password)
    > 46 |       expect(firebase.auth().signInWithEmailAndPassword).toHaveBeenCalled()
         |                                                          ^
      47 |     })
      48 |   })
      49 | })

      at Object.<anonymous> (tests/unit/App.spec.ts:46:58)
```

Comment: not sure if this will work but at a glance, try removing the `()` so try this: `expect(firebase.auth().signInWithEmailAndPassword).toHaveBeenCalled()`

Comment: @RicoKahler doesn't work but it gave me a new error :( i'll update the question hold on

Comment: try importing `firebase` the same you import it in in the file you're testing. jest needs a reference to it so you have to import it, even if you're mocking it.

Comment: @RicoKahler still no luck i'll update the question and errors

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is the uni test solution:

`app.ts`:

```js
import firebase from 'firebase/app';

const App = {
  authenticate: async (email, password) => {
    await firebase.auth().signInWithEmailAndPassword(email, password);
  },
};

export default App;
```

`app.test.ts`:

```js
import App from './app';
import firebase from 'firebase/app';

jest.mock('firebase/app', () => {
  return {
    auth: jest.fn().mockReturnThis(),
    signInWithEmailAndPassword: jest.fn(),
  };
});

describe('61352544', () => {
  it('should pass', async () => {
    const email = 'example@gmail.com';
    const password = '123';
    await App.authenticate(email, password);
    expect(firebase.auth().signInWithEmailAndPassword).toBeCalledWith(email, password);
  });
});
```

unit test results with 100% coverage:

```sh
 PASS  stackoverflow/61352544/app.test.ts (12.122s)
  61352544
    ✓ should pass (9ms)

----------|---------|----------|---------|---------|-------------------
File      | % Stmts | % Branch | % Funcs | % Lines | Uncovered Line #s 
----------|---------|----------|---------|---------|-------------------
All files |     100 |      100 |     100 |     100 |                   
 app.ts   |     100 |      100 |     100 |     100 |                   
----------|---------|----------|---------|---------|-------------------
Test Suites: 1 passed, 1 total
Tests:       1 passed, 1 total
Snapshots:   0 total
Time:        14.061s
```

source code: https://github.com/mrdulin/react-apollo-graphql-starter-kit/tree/master/stackoverflow/61352544

Comment: This worked but however i am still not able to figure out why my code wasnt working and what i got wrong ... can you please tell me what made you think the way you did to solve this problem... appreciate the help :)

Comment: @Phil Why you mock `firebase/app` rather than `firebase`? How do you import `firebase` package in `app.ts`? An important point is you need to use `mockReturnThis()`, so that you can chain call method

Comment: in `app.ts` I import it like this `import firebase from firebase/app` , Therefore i mock `firebase/app`, I import `firebase/app` instead of just `firebase` to just get rid of the warnings in my firebase app :)

Comment: @Phil I change `firebase` to `firebase/app`, it works fine as well.